# Problema con CSS Grid

Tags: html5, css3, css-grid-layout

Tengo el siguiente CSS:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 210px 265px 210px 245px 1fr;
grid-gap: 30px;
grid-template-areas: "layout-uno layout-uno layout-uno"
                     "layout-dos none layout-tres"
                     "layout-cuatro layout-cinco layout-cinco"
                     "layout-seis layout-siete layout-ocho";
```

Me gustaría que la segunda fila, estuviera dividida equitativamente entre el `layout-dos` y el `layout-tres`.

Hay alguna manera de lograr lo anterior, porque cuando se emplea `none` en el  `grid-template-areas` deja un vacío en la maqueta, tal como se aprecia a continuación.

[image: Imagen]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo más aconsejable cuando trabajas con el sistema de áreas del Grid es visualizarlo como cuadrículas.

En este caso se quiere que las filas tengan las siguientes cantidades de columnas:

```
fila1->1
fila2->2
fila3->2
fila4->3
```

Siendo por tanto, el múltiplo `6` para las columnas

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
```

Quedando finalmente así

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.item1 { grid-area: ly1; }
.item2 { grid-area: ly2; }
.item3 { grid-area: ly3; }
.item4 { grid-area: ly4; }
.item5 { grid-area: ly5; }
.item6 { grid-area: ly6; }
.item7 { grid-area: ly7; }
.item8 { grid-area: ly8; }

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 210px 265px 210px 245px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas:
    'ly1 ly1 ly1 ly1 ly1 ly1'
    'ly2 ly2 ly2 ly3 ly3 ly3 '
    'ly4 ly4 ly5 ly5 ly5 ly5'
    'ly6 ly6 ly7 ly7 ly8 ly8';
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">ly1</div>
  <div class="item2">ly2</div>
  <div class="item3">ly3</div>  
  <div class="item4">ly4</div>
  <div class="item5">ly5</div>
  <div class="item6">ly6</div>  
  <div class="item7">ly7</div>
  <div class="item8">ly8</div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente la explicación, la verdad es que no le habia visto de ese modo. Gracias